# ajax load issue

Tags: ajax, load

**I need to load a div using that's id, which is not happening, can anybody have a solution to my issue please? :**

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo CONTENT_PATH?>experts/experts.php",
        data: "#health", // Problem is over here


        success: function(msg){                                         
                                    if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                                    {                                       
                                        $('#cnt_middle').html(msg);
                                        $('#loading').css('display','none');
                                        //$('.content_bottom').hide();
                                    }
                                },
                                error:  function(){
                                    $.Zebra_Dialog('<?php echo LOAD_ERROR; ?>');
                                    document.clear();
                                    $('#loading').css('display','none');
                                }                           

                            });
```

thanks.

Comment: so you want "data" attribute to have content of div?

Answer (score 0):

The $.ajax() functions 'data' property should be in some GET/POST conform data format.

Some examples:

```
data: ({pageid: 10}),
...
data: ({pagename: 'some-page-name'}),
...
data: $('#myform input').serialize(),
...
data: 'pageid=10&num=5',
... etc
```

Comment: Is that like this?
                                                                                                          
/*************************/

type: "POST",

        url: "<?php echo CONTENT_PATH?>experts/experts.php",
        data: $('#health').serialize(),
        type:'POST',

Comment: If the '#health' means a div id, yes, it could be working, but i suggest you to serialize only the input fields you want to pass to the ajax request. Like this: '#health input', or if you specified a class for the input: '#health .inputclass'